# Need help to make C# code simpler

Tags: c#, lego-mindstorms

I need to work with a lot of calculation with C#.

I wonder if possible to make the code simpler by calling the code fragments.

For example:

I have 3 calculation:

a -> x = (x + 2)/0.4

b -> x = 2x + (5*(x^2))

c -> x = 0.435 + 0.5x

I want to do calculation with that.

So, instead of writing all the calculation,

I want to just calling them whenever I need them for example

```
{
x = 3.5
result = a + c
}
```

or

```
{
x = 3.5
result = (b/a + c) + 2b
}
```

If u are familiar with Ev3 lego mindstorm. Its the thing that we call MyBlock.

Thanks in advance

Comment: how about writing a [method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_methods.htm) for each equation?

Comment: Also a good read, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods

Comment: yeah....method..its what Im seeking for..thanks..:)

Answer (score 0):

you can declare some properties.

```
    double x
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    double a
    {
        get
        {
            return (x + 2) / 0.4;
        }
    }
    double b
    {
        get
        {
        return 2*x + (5*(x*x));
        }
    }
    double c
    {
        get
        {
            return 0.435 + 0.5 * x;
        }
    }
```

Comment: ill take a look with this method too..:)